# How can I clean up empty fields when converting CSV to JSON with Miller?

Tags: json, csv, miller

I have several CSV files of item data for a game I'm messing around with that I need to convert to JSON for consumption. The data can be quite irregular with several empty fields per record, which makes for sort of ugly JSON output.

Example with dummy values:

```
Id,Name,Value,Type,Properties/1,Properties/2,Properties/3,Properties/4
01:Foo:13,Foo,13,ACME,CanExplode,IsRocket,,
02:Bar:42,Bar,42,,IsRocket,,,
03:Baz:37,Baz,37,BlackMesa,CanExplode,IsAlive,IsHungry,
```

Converted output:

```
[
{
  "Id": "01:Foo:13",
  "Name": "Foo",
  "Value": 13,
  "Type": "ACME",
  "Properties": ["CanExplode", "IsRocket", ""]
},
{
  "Id": "02:Bar:42",
  "Name": "Bar",
  "Value": 42,
  "Type": "",
  "Properties": ["IsRocket", "", ""]
},
{
  "Id": "03:Baz:37",
  "Name": "Baz",
  "Value": 37,
  "Type": "BlackMesa",
  "Properties": ["CanExplode", "IsAlive", "IsHungry"]
}
]
```

So far I've been quite successful with using `Miller`. I've managed to remove completely empty columns from the CSV as well as aggregate the `Properties/X` columns into a single array.

But now I'd like to do two more things to improve the output format to make consuming the JSON easier:

- remove empty strings `""` from the `Properties` array
- replace the other empty strings `""` (e.g. `Type` of the second record) with `null`

Desired output:

```
[
{
  "Id": "01:Foo:13",
  "Name": "Foo",
  "Value": 13,
  "Type": "ACME",
  "Properties": ["CanExplode", "IsRocket"]
},
{
  "Id": "02:Bar:42",
  "Name": "Bar",
  "Value": 42,
  "Type": null,
  "Properties": ["IsRocket"]
},
{
  "Id": "03:Baz:37",
  "Name": "Baz",
  "Value": 37,
  "Type": "BlackMesa",
  "Properties": ["CanExplode", "IsAlive", "IsHungry"]
}
]
```

Is there a way to achieve that with `Miller`?

My current commands are:

- `mlr -I --csv remove-empty-columns file.csv` to clean up the columns
- `mlr --icsv --ojson --jflatsep '/' --jlistwrap cat file.csv > file.json` for the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not probably the way you want to do it. I use also jq.

Running

```bash
mlr --c2j  --jflatsep '/' --jlistwrap remove-empty-columns then cat input.csv | \
jq '.[].Properties|=map(select(length > 0))' | \
jq '.[].Type|=(if . == "" then null else . end)'
```

you will have

```
[
  {
    "Id": "01:Foo:13",
    "Name": "Foo",
    "Value": 13,
    "Type": "ACME",
    "Properties": [
      "CanExplode",
      "IsRocket"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "02:Bar:42",
    "Name": "Bar",
    "Value": 42,
    "Type": null,
    "Properties": [
      "IsRocket"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "03:Baz:37",
    "Name": "Baz",
    "Value": 37,
    "Type": "BlackMesa",
    "Properties": [
      "CanExplode",
      "IsAlive",
      "IsHungry"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller, you can "filter out" the empty fields from each record with:

```bash
mlr --c2j --jflatsep '/' --jlistwrap put '
    $* = select($*, func(k,v) {return v != ""})
' file.csv
```

**remark:** actually, we're building a new record containing the non-empty fields instead of deleting the empty fields from the record; the final result is equivalent though:

```json
[
{
  "Id": "01:Foo:13",
  "Name": "Foo",
  "Value": 13,
  "Type": "ACME",
  "Properties": ["CanExplode", "IsRocket"]
},
{
  "Id": "02:Bar:42",
  "Name": "Bar",
  "Value": 42,
  "Properties": ["IsRocket"]
},
{
  "Id": "03:Baz:37",
  "Name": "Baz",
  "Value": 37,
  "Type": "BlackMesa",
  "Properties": ["CanExplode", "IsAlive", "IsHungry"]
}
]
```